# Lightbox unable to Enlarge Images

Tags: php, image, lightbox, bigcommerce

This week our product pages have been not working as intended.  When clicking the product image thumbnail to enlarge, the lightbox window loads and just continues to load, never displaying the image.  It was working before and I have no access to these scripts and files, since they are loaded through PHP that I have no access to.  We are on BigCommerce's platform, but BC will not help me because we have customized our template.  I have poured through the source code and cannot find what could be causing this issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Link to a product page: http://www.inflatableboats.net/demo-zodiac-pro-open-650-t-top-neo-2016-with-twin-yamaha-f70-four-stroke/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
%%Panel.HTMLHead%%
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_AppPath%%/javascript/jquery/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_AppPath%%/javascript/product.functions.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_AppPath%%/javascript/product.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
    <div id="Container">
    %%Panel.Header%%

    <div id="Wrapper">
        %%Panel.WrapperBanner%%

        <div class="Left" id="LayoutColumn1">
            %%Panel.SideCategoryList%%
            %%Panel.SideNewProducts%%
            %%Panel.SideNewsletterBox%%
            %%Panel.SideLiveChatServices%%
        </div>
        <div class="Content" id="LayoutColumn2">



            %%Panel.ProductBreadcrumb%%

            %%Panel.ProductDetails%%

            <div id="Fees">
<p id="FeeHeader"><strong>Standard Fees Apply</strong></p>
<a class="tooltip" style="float: left;" href="#"> PDI: <span> <img class="callout" src="http://inflatableboats.net/template/feebox/callout.gif" alt="" /> <strong>Pre-Delivery Inspection</strong><br /> Standard Fee for services performed and products used on each new vessel, requested by all manufacturers to validate and assist in all warranties.<br /><br />We install a deep cycle marine battery, fully rig steering components, complete electrical and systems check. We conduct a full system check on the motor, fill with oil, fluids, and fuel, then test run in a test tank.<br /><br />Once everything is tuned and prepared, a sea trial is performed with two Specialists to achieve ideal RPM-to-top-speed ratio, ensuring the boat gets on plane properly, and all systems operate on water.<br /><br />Afterwards a full detail is performed on the tubes, deck, and hull to be turn-key ready for the customer. </span> </a>
<p style="float: left;">&nbsp;</p>
<a class="tooltip" style="float: left;" href="#"> Destination Fee: <span> <img class="callout" src="http://inflatableboats.net/template/feebox/callout.gif" alt="" /> <strong>Destination Fees are set by Zodiac.</strong><br /> Standard Fee both vehicle and vessel dealerships are charged from a manufacturer to ship product to dealerships </span> </a>
<p style="float: left;">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="quote">

                <a class="btn lightbox-40737220632144" style="cursor: pointer;"><img id="quotebutton" style="" src="http://inflatableboats.net/template/img/request-a-quote.png" name="quotebutton" /></a>             
                <a href="/financing/"><img id="financebutton" style="" src="http://inflatableboats.net/template/img/finance-button.png" name="quotebutton" /></a>       
            </div>

            %%Panel.ProductTabs%%
            %%Panel.ProductDescription%%
            %%Panel.ProductVideos%%
            %%Panel.ProductWarranty%%
            %%Panel.ProductOtherDetails%%
            %%Panel.SimilarProductsByTag%%
            %%Panel.ProductByCategory%%
            %%Panel.ProductVendorsOtherProducts%%
            %%Panel.SimilarProductsByCustomerViews%%

        </div>
        <div class="Right" id="LayoutColumn3">
            %%Panel.SideCurrencySelector%%
            %%Panel.SideProductAddToWishList%%
            %%Panel.SideProductRelated%%
            %%Panel.SideProductRecentlyViewed%%
        </div>
        <br class="Clear" />
    </div>

    %%Panel.Footer%%
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ProductOtherDetails .ProductDetailsGrid .DetailRow").each(function(){

var label = $(".Label",this).text();

if ( label === 'PDI:') {
var pdiAmount = $(".Value",this).text();
pdiAmount = pdiAmount.replace(/\t/g,"");
pdiAmount = pdiAmount.replace(/\n/g,"");
//console.log("PDI is " + pdiAmount);
$("#Fees p:nth-of-type(2)").text(pdiAmount);
}

if ( label === 'DF:') {
var dfiAmount = $(".Value",this).text();
dfiAmount = dfiAmount.replace(/\t/g,"");
dfiAmount = dfiAmount.replace(/\n/g,"");
//console.log("DF is " + dfiAmount);
$("#Fees p:nth-of-type(3)").text(dfiAmount);
}

})


});
</script>
<script src="https://form.jotform.com/static/feedback2.js?3.3.REV" type="text/javascript"> var JFL_40737220632144 = new JotformFeedback({ formId: '40737220632144', base: 'https://form.jotform.com/', windowTitle: 'Request a Quote', background: '#B10D13', fontColor: '#FFFFFF', type: 'false', height: 500, width: 700, openOnLoad: false }); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think that maybe it is caused by a TypeError, but do not know how I can fix this.  Image linked below.  It points me to the first line of the source, which is the HTML Doctype.  That doesn't make sense to me.

[image: Link to Image showing Error]

Comment: In the console appears this error `TypeError: jQuery.fn.fancybox is undefined`. Is this `fancybox` script loaded?

Comment: It should be.  I have no control over the fancybox script because BC gives me no access to it.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.inflatableboats.net/js/"></script> is returning a 404 as well. It looks like the path is wrong since there is no JS folder in the root directory of your BC store.

Comment: Dang, these are all things outside my control.  I see the fancybox script error, but with no way to edit the script or code, could there be anything in my on my page that could be interfering?  I have added my product page template html above.  I can add the HTMLHead and/or Header if that could be the culprit.

Comment: I did find where the /js/ script was in the htmlheader.  Here is what I have access to, which grabs the "fill-in-the-blank" information via PHP:

<script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/js/%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>